# Generate random numbers from 1 to 7 using a given random generator function

Tags: math, random, probability

Create a function that generates numbers 1 to 7 with equal probability using a function that generates numbers 1 to 5 randomly with equal probability.

I modified one of the previous answers. Is it correct?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ran rand()%5
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a[2][5] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 0, 0, 0}};
    int ct[8] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i<50000000; i++){
        int j = ran;
        while(j>1){
            j = ran;
        }
        int k = ran;
        if(a[j][k]>0)
            ct[a[j][k]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i<=7; i++){
        cout<<ct[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I had the following output:

```
4997165
4998128
4997312
5002487
5000661
4998637
4999720
```

Please tell if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: It's not advisable to use macros to "simulate" functions (`ran`) but if you _must_ do so, learn to protect the expansion properly: `#define ran (rand()%5)` otherwise you may get unexpected results if you use the macro in an expression. In this case, in the way you use it, it may not matter, but for other macros, used in different ways, it will.

Comment: Your way of mapping 1-5 on to 1-7 isn't ideal: I haven't studied it to see if the distribution is expected to be uniform or not, but the main problem is that you're "asking" for 50 million numbers and getting just shy of 35 million.

Comment: @TripeHound the question was to generate all numbers 1 to 7 with equal probability. The rest 15 million were 0 which I ignored.

Comment: @TripeHound: It's much worse that that. The number of draws from the 1-5 random number generator will be far in excess of 50 million: somewhere around 175 million (each iteration of the main loop involves an average of 2.5 draws to get j, and then 1 draw to get k), so an average of 5 draws per output value. While I believe the OP's solution is correct, it's possible to do it much more efficiently. The theoretical limit would be log(7) / log(5) ~= 1.209 draws per generated deviate, and it should be possible to get close to that without too much effort.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'm aware that there's some spinning in the `while` loop, but -- in a way -- at least it _is_ spinning, so you'll get a "valid" `j` each time. Although it's a very inefficient way of doing it, my problem with the second test is that it _doesn't_ spin: sometimes it will generate a valid number and sometimes it won't.

Comment: @TripeHound: Right, fair enough. The code should really be refactored so that there's a core generator function that's guaranteed to give one result between 1 and 7 per call.

Comment: @SurajTripathi: Your question might fare better on the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Note that your function `ran` doesn't match the specification: it returns integers in the range 0 through 4 inclusive, not 1 through 5 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern C++ solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>

template <unsigned int Min, unsigned int Max>
class imbued_urng
{
public:
    using result_type = unsigned int;

    static constexpr result_type min() { return Min; }
    static constexpr result_type max() { return Max; }

    imbued_urng(const std::function<result_type()>& source) : random{ source } {}
    imbued_urng(const imbued_urng& rhs) = delete;
    imbued_urng& operator=(const imbued_urng& rhs) = delete;

    result_type operator()() { return random(); }

private:
    const std::function<result_type()>& random;
};

int main()
{
    // Create a random number engine
    std::mt19937::result_type seed = std::random_device{}();
    std::cout << "seed = " << seed << std::endl;
    auto engine = std::mt19937{ seed };

    // Create the rand5 distribution
    auto const dist5{ std::uniform_int_distribution<> {1, 5} };
    auto const rand5{ std::function<unsigned int()>{ [&engine, &dist5] { return dist5(engine); } } };

    auto const n = 32;
    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, " "), n, rand5);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Create a uniform random number generator based on rand5
    imbued_urng<1, 5> urng { rand5 };

    // Create the rand7 distribution
    auto const dist7{ std::uniform_int_distribution<> {1, 7} };
    auto const rand7{ std::function<unsigned int()>{ [&urng, &dist7] { return dist7(urng); } } };

    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, " "), n, rand7);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is actually an interview problem. I don't think that this is the intended answer. It might be correct, but something simpler was expected. I will be grateful if you can find mistake in my implementation.

Comment: @SurajTripathi Your solution certainly isn't the _best_, mostly because of all the looping. Also, you haven't created a _function_ that generates a number from 1 to 7 (which is what I suspect they want)... and the "inside" of your `for` loop doesn't really do this since sometimes it won't generate a (valid) number at all.  At a _minimum_, you could wrap the inside of the `for` in a "validity-test" loop and stick it in a function -- ideally, you'd look at a more efficient way of using multiple 1-5 picks to generate the range 1-7